# Client can't see DNS server on Ubuntu 12.04 Server with two ethernet cards

Tags: networking, system-installation

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 Server with Webmin, bind9, and a GUI. It has two ethernet cards: eth0 coming in, and eth1 to talk to clients. My client gets an IP address from DHCP, but cannot connect because "DNS is not responding" (Windows 7), even though it's detected. I was seeing a lease, but changed something and now I don't see a lease in webmin.

**Edit 1**

netstat output:

```
Proto  Recv-Q  Send-Q  Local_Addr        Foreign_Addrs  ST      PID
tcp    0       0       127.0.0.1:3306    0.0.0.0:*      LISTEN  220/mysqld
tcp    0       0       10.0.0.254:53     0.0.0.0:*      LISTEN  9782/named
tcp    0       0       192.168.1.216:53  0.0.0.0:*      LISTEN  9782/named
tcp    0       0       127.0.0.1:53      0.0.0.0:*      LISTEN  9782/named
tcp    0       0       0.0.0.0:22        0.0.0.0:*      LISTEN  9724/sshd
tcp    0       0       127.0.0.1:953     0.0.0.0:*      LISTEN  ???
```

Comment: This is a bad question. You don't even tell us whether DHCP still works (for the client). It does not tell us anything about what you have done (or tried). Does that mean you have tried nothing? Do you have SSH access?

Answer (score 0):

You should check whether

1. DNS is running (`ps`, `netstat --inet -lnp`, DNS start script)
2. DNS queries from the client reach the server (`tcpdump -i eth1 -n udp port 53`)
3. the firewall blocks access to DNS (`iptables -L INPUT -nv`)
4. the DNS server is configured correctly (`host unix.stackexchange.com 127.0.0.1`)

Comment: 2. tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth1, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes

Comment: I sorry I did all for steps I have answers but i don't know how to post them correctly to your answer.

Comment: @JuliePearce You should edit your question and add the information there. You should indent output with four spaces "    " so that it gets the correct formatting.

Comment: 1)Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Addr Foreign Addrs ST PID<br/> tcp|0|0|127.0.0.1:3306|0.0.0.0:*|LISTEN|220/mysqld<br/>     <br/>tcp|0|0|10.0.0.254:53 |0.0.0.0:*|LISTEN|9782/named <br/>     
tcp|0|0|192.168.1.216:53|0.0.0.0:*|LISTEN|9782/named  <br/>  
tcp|0|0|127.0.0.1:53|0.0.0.0:*|LISTEN|9782/named   <br/>   
tcp|0 0|0.0.0.0:22|0.0.0.0:*|LISTEN |9724/sshd     <br/>  
tcp|0|0|127.0.0.1:953|0.0.0.0:*|LISTEN|

Comment: 3.Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 24308 packets, 10M bytes)
pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Comment: 4. is this found /etc/host? if so i have 127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       sname.com

Comment: My server gets internet.  My client sees the network gets a dhcp ip lease ( i see that in ipconfig) but gets error that "DNS is detected but not respondding"   (I space bar 4 times and it still looks as it does now)